# how can i make form with laravelcollective?

Tags: laravel

i'm new in laravel i'm setting up laravelcollective forms in my project

i want to know the structure of the laravel collective forms

for example if you can make an example of form with filled data name like this to understand

```
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ FORM::label('?','?')  }}
        {{ FORM::text('?', '', ['?' => '?') }}

    </div>
```

also tell me how can i convert this normal input :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="switch" />
<label class="labell" for="switch">Toggle</label>
```

to laravel collective form

and also how can i use csrf in my laravelcollective form to protect it ?

Comment: I strongly recommend you to read the documentation. You can do it [here](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html).

Comment: i'm strongly looking for answer because i did that but nothing